# Not good condition String after json convert

Tags: c#, json

I have example convert to string and json. The problem is that I see code of character:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize("string here"); //to json
string str = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(string)).ToString(); //to string
```

After this I see String:

> Hello \u0027test\u0027 From Test Controller! \r\n08.10.2013 16:55:20

Can I convert in type like this:

> Hello 'test' From Test Controller
>
> 08.10.2013 16:55:20

Comment: you arent showing us the key part of code.  where does "Hello"  and "From Test Controller" come from?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe try to unescape string:

```
string json = serializer.Serialize("string here");
string decodedJson = Uri.UnescapeDataString(json);
string str = serializer.Deserialize(decodedJson , typeof(string)).ToString();
```